# Exception : mockito wanted but not invoked, Actually there were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have interface

```
Interface MyInterface {
  myMethodToBeVerified (String, String);
}
```

And implementation of interface is

```
class MyClassToBeTested implements MyInterface {
   myMethodToBeVerified(String, String) {
    …….
   }
}
```

I have another class

```
class MyClass {
    MyInterface myObj = new MyClassToBeTested();
    public void abc(){
         myObj.myMethodToBeVerified (new String(“a”), new String(“b”));
    }
}
```

I am trying to write JUnit for MyClass. I have done

```
class MyClassTest {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
  
    @Mock
    MyInterface myInterface;

    testAbc(){
         myClass.abc();
         verify(myInterface).myMethodToBeVerified(new String(“a”), new String(“b”));
    }
}
```

But I am getting       **mockito wanted but not invoked, Actually there were zero interactions with this mock** at verify call.

can anyone suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 31):

You need to inject mock inside the class you're testing. At the moment you're interacting with the real object, not with the mock one. You can fix the code in a following way:

```
void testAbc(){
     myClass.myObj = myInteface;
     myClass.abc();
     verify(myInterface).myMethodToBeVerified(new String("a"), new String("b"));
}
```

although it would be a wiser choice to extract all initialization code into `@Before`

```
@Before
void setUp(){
     myClass = new myClass();
     myClass.myObj = myInteface;
}

@Test
void testAbc(){
     myClass.abc();
     verify(myInterface).myMethodToBeVerified(new String("a"), new String("b"));
}
```

Comment: Why can't we use **Mockito.mock** here?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky : We can use Mockito.mock, for that we have to use one setter method for myObj and set the mocked object to myObj.

Comment: How is `myClass.myObj = myInteface;` valid? myObj is not a method of myClass

Answer (score 10):

Your class `MyClass` creates a new `MyClassToBeTested`, instead of using your mock.  [My article on the Mockito wiki](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation) describes two ways of dealing with this.

Comment: HikariDataSourceProvider dataSourceProvider = mock(DataSourceProvider.class);

        verify(dataSourceProvider).shutdown();

what is problem in it

Answer (score 8):

@Jk1's answer is fine, but Mockito also allows for more succinct injection using annotations:

```
@InjectMocks MyClass myClass; //@InjectMocks automatically instantiates too
@Mock MyInterface myInterface
```

But regardless of which method you use, the annotations are not being processed (not even your @Mock) unless you somehow call the static `MockitoAnnotation.initMocks()` or annotate the class with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.

Answer (score 2):

@jk1 answer is perfect, since @igor Ganapolsky asked, why can't we use Mockito.mock here? i post this answer.

For that we have provide one setter method for myobj and set the myobj value with mocked object.

```
class MyClass {
    MyInterface myObj;

    public void abc() {
        myObj.myMethodToBeVerified (new String("a"), new String("b"));
    }

    public void setMyObj(MyInterface obj)
    {
        this.myObj=obj;
    }
}
```

In our Test class, we have to write below code

```
class MyClassTest {

MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    @Mock
    MyInterface myInterface;

    @test
    testAbc() {
        myclass.setMyObj(myInterface); //it is good to have in @before method
        myClass.abc();
        verify(myInterface).myMethodToBeVerified(new String("a"), new String("b"));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This  exception can also be thrown if say, you expect thisMethod() to execute, but it didn't. It didn't because it's inside a condition that was not met.

For example, if you have some unit test that says verify thisMethod() is executed, but in fact, it was not because varX and varY are not equal.

```
//method expected to be called.    
if( varX == varY){
     thisMethod();
  }

 //test
 Mockito.verify(foo).thisMethod();
```