# Java unit test with inner object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have following two classes

```
public class SampleTest {
   public Integer getResult() {
     Test1 test1 = new Test1(5);
     Integer j = doSomeThing(test1);
     return j;
   }

   public Integer doSomeThing(Test1 test1){
     Integer p = test1.getValue();
     return p+1;
   }
}

public class Test1 {
  Integer i;
  Test1(Integer i){
    this.i = i*2;
  }

  Integer getValue(){
    return i;
  }
```

I would like to unit test SampleTest getResult() but would like to Mock Test1() insider this, so that i returns whatever value i set in UnitTests. I can't change any of these class.

I tried few pattern using Mockito but no success.

Kindly suggest some good pointers.

Comment: Is `SampleTest` the _subject_ of the test?  If so, then your problem is, it is not designed for testing.  The problem is, it gets the `test1` instance by calling a static method (i.e., the `Test1` constructor).  `static` is the enemy of testing.  You need to be able to _inject_ a mock `test1` somehow.

Comment: Have you looked at Powermock? It has lots of useful extensions for these types of cases.

Comment: Yes I need to test SampleTest, which is a legacy code, i am trying to find how to inject test1 in it.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20551926/.  Perhaps you'll find an answer there.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need the Mockito extension [Powermock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) for that, since it requires changing the bytecode of the class. See [*Mock construction of new objects*](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) for instructions on how to do so.

The main tool will probably be `expectNew` or `createMockAndExpectNew`. Ex (untested and probably missing something, but general direction):

```
Test1 mockedTest1 = createMockAndExpectNew(Test1, any(Integer));
expect(mockedTest1.getValue()).andReturn(42);
replayAll(); // setup all objects maintained by Powermock.
assertEquals(new SampleTest().getResult(), 43);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use Mockito with the classes you currently have. 
I would suggest you to add a constructor for `SampleTest` in which you pass a test1 instance:

```
public SampleTest(Test1 test1) {
    this.test1 = test1;
}
```

Then your getResult method can use this `Test1` client:

```
public Integer getResult() {
    Integer j = doSomeThing(this.test1);
    return j;
}
```

Finally you can mock your test1 instance and make it return whatever you want:

```
Test1 test1 = Mockito.mock(Test1.class);
Mockito.when(test1.getValue()).thenReturn(42);
SampleTest sampleTest = new SampleTest(test1);
Assertions.assertThat(sampleTest.getResult()).isEqualTo(43);
```

With this design you loose couple between both classes and your test clearly shows the relationship between them.