# Getting Mockito exception while running code

Tags: java, mockito

I have a code as belows :

```
public class D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = Mockito.mock(C.class);
        G g = Mockito.mock(G.class);
        doReturn(g).when(c).getResult(eq(new A(new B())), eq(new F()));
        verify(c, times(1)).getResult(eq(new A(new B())), eq(new F()));
    }
}
```

When I try to run the code , I get this message :

```
Exception in thread "main" Wanted but not invoked:
c.getResult(
    info.sanaulla.A@46f5f779,
    info.sanaulla.F@1c2c22f3
);
-> at info.sanaulla.D.main(D.java:15)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at info.sanaulla.D.main(D.java:15)
```

I referred this link but couldn't understand how to modify the above code to make it workable : [Exception : mockito wanted but not invoked, Actually there were zero interactions with this mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551926/exception-mockito-wanted-but-not-invoked-actually-there-were-zero-interaction)

Can someone please help.

The above error got resolved by adding c.getResult(new A(new B()), new F()); above

```
Exception in thread "main" Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
c.getResult(
    info.sanaulla.A@12bc6874,
    info.sanaulla.F@4c75cab9
);
-> at info.sanaulla.D.main(D.java:17)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
c.getResult(
    info.sanaulla.A@de0a01f,
    info.sanaulla.F@1ef7fe8e
);
-> at info.sanaulla.D.main(D.java:16)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at info.sanaulla.D.main(D.java:17)
```

What am I Missing?
Classes I have been using :

```
public final class A {
    B b;
    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public class B {
}

public class C {
    public C() {

    }

    public G getResult(A a, F f) {
        G g = new G();
        return g;
    }
}
public class F {

}
```

Comment: Which class is under test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never call a function of mock c.

`verify` checks if the mock c is called one time in your test case.

UPDATE:

change you code to:

```
public class D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = Mockito.mock(C.class);
        G g = Mockito.mock(G.class);
        B b = new B();
        A a = new A();
        F f = new F();
        doReturn(g).when(c).getResult(eq(a), eq(f));
        c.getResult(a, f); 
        verify(c, times(1)).getResult(eq(a), eq(f));

    }
}
```

Because in your code you ever create a new Instance of an object, wich are different after every initilization.

Comment: c.getResult(new A(new B()), new F()); and it worked but now getting some another error.

Comment: @user3057107 as i wrote, you created two objects of class A wich are not the same. ans the same with f

Comment: As you can ee here `info.sanaulla.A@12bc6874` is not equals `info.sanaulla.A@de0a01f,`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public class D {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // mock a dummy so that we do not have to call A's actual methods
        A a = Mockito.mock(A.class);
        when(a.foo()).thenReturn("bar");            

        // run the actual method of C
        new C().getResult(a, new F());

        // verifies that this method was called
        verify(c, times(1)).getResult(any(A.class), any(F.class));
    }
}
```

You should never `mock` the class that you want to test, as that will create a dummy object. All the `when` methods are for telling your dummy classes what to return when their methods are called.

Comment: Getting an error like this : Exception in thread "main" org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type C and is not a mock!
Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
See the examples of correct verifications:
    verify(mock).someMethod();
    verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
    verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();
 at info.sanaulla.D.main(D.java:26)