# Mockito outputs "wanted but not invoked, Actually there were zero interactions with this mock"

Tags: android, mockito

I am getting this error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
view.showPlayerActivity(null);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I have this code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Log.class)
public class MyDriverPresenterTest  {

    @Mock
    private MyDriveRepository mydriveRepository;

    private MyDrivePresenter drivePresenter;

    private Drive drive;

    private List<Drive> driveList;

    @Before
    public void setUpMyRecrdingsPresenter(){

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Log.class);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        drivePresenter = new MyDrivePresenter();

        drive = new Drive("Roar",false,1521708960,11);
        driveList.add(drive);

    }

    @Test
    public void testDriveClicked(){
        Uri uri=mydriveRepository.
        getMyDriveItemSelectedPathUri(drive.toFile().getName());
        verify(view).showPlayerActivity(uri);       
    }

}
```

class MyDrivePresenter has method

```
@Override
    public void onDriveClicked(Drive drive) {
        Uri uri = mydriveRepository.getMyDriveItemSelectedPathUri(drive.toFile().getName());
        Log.i("TAG", "onRecordingClicked: "+uri);
        view.showPlayerActivity(uri);
    }
```

and MyDriveRepository has method

```
public Uri getMyDriveItemSelectedPathUri(String name){
        Uri pathUri;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            pathUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"com.mypackagename",new File(getUserMixDir(),name));
        }else{
            pathUri = Uri.parse("file://"+new File(getUserMixDir(),name));
        }

        return pathUri;
    }
```

mydriveRepository.getMyDriveItemSelectedPathUri keeps returning me null.
I tried looking at the following link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551926/exception-mockito-wanted-but-not-invoked-actually-there-were-zero-interaction?rq=1` but couldn't really find a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're mocking you repository, so you need to provide a behaviour for when the presenter calls the repository methods:

```
when(mydriveRepository.getMyDriveItemSelectedPathUri(anyString())).thenReturn(mockedUri);
```

So your test will look like this:

```
@Mock
MyDriveRepository mydriveRepository;

@Mock
Uri mockedUri;


@Test
public void testDriveClicked() {
    String filePath = "aPAth";

    presenter.onDriveClicked(drive);
    Uri uri = mydriveRepository.getMyDriveItemSelectedPathUri(filePath);
    verify(view).showPlayerActivity(uri);
}
```

So basically here you'll test if the presenter calls that view method with the pseudo generated URI. You're telling the framework (mockito) to return a mocked URI when the presenter calls the getMyDriveItemSelectedPathUri method on the repository. Then the real test comes when you test if the method in the view was called by the presenter.

Comment: It doesn't work. I am still getting Wanted but not invoked:
view.showPlayerActivity(uri);Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Comment: Own yeah, I forgot to actually call the method on the presenter. presenter.onDriveClicked(drive);. I've edited the answer

Comment: Thanks alot. Really helped me