# No interactions with mock in unit test - java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm a bit new to mocking, but I have a class (lets call it ClassA) with methods including one that returns a put response after sending an item to a database.

This class is called in another class (lets say ClassB), but classB's methods do not return the response from ClassA.

Given the following structure for ClassA and ClassB:

```
private final DatabaseClientFactory dbClientFactory;
private final DatabaseClient dbClient; 
... other instance vars ...
public ClassA() {
    ClassA(new ..params, new dbClientFactory());
}

public ClassA(...some parameters ... DatabaseClientFactory dbClientFactory) {
    ....
    this.dbClientFactory = dbClientFactory;
    this.dbClient = this.dbClientFactory.get(); 
}

public PutResponse methodA() {
    ...
    dbClient.put(...);
}
```

and ClassB:

```
public ClassB(...some params..., ClassA aClass) {

}
public void methodB() {
    aClass.methodA();
    ...more random code
}
```

I've tried to set up the mock equivalent to this logic:

```
public class classBTest {
    @Mock
    private ClassA aClass = new ClassA();
    private ClassB bClass; 
    public void setUp() throws IOException {    
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        bClass = spy(ClassB(aClass));
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        bClass.methodB(); 
       when(aClass.methodA(any())).thenReturn(PutResponse.newBuilder().build());
        verify(aClass, Mockito.times(1)).methodA(any());
    }
```

I kept getting an error that

```
Wanted but not invoked:
aClass.methodA(<any>);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

So I tried a few things
I tried changing the constructor call of bClass to be `bClass = spy(ClassB(mock(ClassA.class)))`

I tried adding             `when(classA.methodA(any())).thenReturn(PutResponse.newBuilder().build());`
to the setUp method.

I tried setting up spy on an instance of ClassA, with mocked parameters

I tried using @InjectMocks but ended up with a null pointer exception.

But now I'm stuck

Any suggestions?

*Note that ClassA has an empty constructor by default

Comment: That error is telling you that `bClass.method` isn't calling `aClass.method` at all.  As to why not, I guess you'd have to show us the code for `ClassB` before anyone can tell you that.

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551926/exception-mockito-wanted-but-not-invoked-actually-there-were-zero-interaction

Comment: @PaulMarcelinBejan thank you! tried all the suggestions but still didnt work :(

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I gave as much details as was relevant -- mocking isn't about the code, its about the setup of tests

Comment: I had a similar issue when I use “when” for the first time. Essentially it is trying to say that the test you did, didn’t call methodA, maybe for some if condition. So you have to chenge the input, to be able to reach the line where the methodA is called, or remove the when part.

Comment: Thanks, Mary, I know what mocking is (kind of why I'm currently the all-time highest-scoring provider of answers in the Mockito tag).  But like I said, that message means that in your application code, the method of `bClass` isn't calling the method in `aClass`.  That means you've either failed to inject the `aClass` object properly into the `bClass` object, or that your code simply doesn't call `aClass.method`.  Now you've shown the code for `ClassB` (and assuming you've shown it accurately), it looks like the problem might be the former.  Maybe there's a problem in the `ClassB` constructor.